# The content disappears when i make the navbar fixed

Tags: position, navbar, fixed

So me header is like that [The nav bar without positioning](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aUpIb.png)

and when i turn on position fixed the content disappears behind the nav so how can i fix this

[my nav bar after fixing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tUfLF.png)

Comment: *{
 padding: 0;
 margin: 0;
}
body {
 font-family: 'Ubuntu', sans-serif;
background-color: #ccc;
height: 884px;
}
header {
}
nav {
 height: 90px;
 background-color: #fff;
    box-shadow: -5px 2px #aaaaaa;
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
}

Answer (score 1):

z-index may solve your problem. set z-index to 2 or greater...